# Canvas wont append correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

With the current code, the canvas appends on the end of the page.
I'm trying to move my canvas with id "can" from the bottom of my page to a div with id "saletop".

I've tried using appendChild and append directly from my sale_canvas function, but it didn't show.

**functions.js**

```
function sale_canvas() {

?>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {              

                const width = 750;
                const height = 50;
                const centerY = height / 2;
                const amplitude = 0 ;
                const speed = 50;
                const degrees = 45;

                let startTime = 0;
                let previousTime = 0;
                let pausedTime = 0;
                let paused = false;
                let canvas, ctx;
                let charObjs;

                const start = () => {
                  canvas = document.createElement('canvas');            
                  canvas.width = width;
                  canvas.height = height;
                  canvas.id = 'can';
                  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                  window.addEventListener('blur', () => {
                    if (!paused) {
                      paused = true;
                      pausedTime = Date.now() - startTime;
                    } 
                  });

             ** the rest of the code **

                };

                start();            

        });

    </script>
<?php

}
add_action('wp_head', 'sale_canvas');

function sale_replace() {

?>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {              
            $("#can").appendTo("#saletop");
        });

    </script>
<?php

}
add_action('wp_head', 'sale_replace');
```

**page.php**

```
<div class="salebanenr">
 <div class="row">          
  <div class="col-12 col-md-12" id="saletop">

  </div>                    
 </div>
</div>
```

The canvas is appending but its empty, without content.

FULL CODE HERE: https://pastebin.com/gm2GMTcK

Comment: Is the code that adds something to the canvas in that section marked "** the rest of the code **"?

Comment: @Andy i just posted a link

Answer (score -1):

I don't see what is the problem - made a test and it works just fine.
note that you might want to append the canvas directly into the div. no append it to the body first.

But still your code works as expected: [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/n0c95t3m/1/)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  const width = 750;
  const height = 50;
  const centerY = height / 2;
  const amplitude = 0;
  const speed = 50;
  const degrees = 45;

  let startTime = 0;
  let previousTime = 0;
  let pausedTime = 0;
  let paused = false;
  let canvas, ctx;
  let charObjs;

  const start = () => {
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    canvas.id = 'can';
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    window.addEventListener('blur', () => {
      if (!paused) {
        paused = true;
        pausedTime = Date.now() - startTime;
      }
    });
    window.addEventListener('focus', () => {
      if (paused) {
        paused = false;
        startTime = Date.now() - pausedTime;
        animate();
      }
    });

    charObjs = initScrollText('SALE SALE SALE SALE SALE SALE SALE SALE');

    startTime = Date.now();
    previousTime = getTime();
    animate();
  };

  const initScrollText = (text) => {
    ctx.font = 'bold 32px Courier New';

    let position = 0;

    return text.split('').map((char) => {
      const width = ctx.measureText(char).width;
      const charObj = {
        char,
        width,
        position
      };

      position += width;
      return charObj;
    });
  };

  const getTime = () => {
    return paused ?
      pausedTime :
      Date.now() - startTime;
  };

  const scrollText = (dt) => {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';

    charObjs.forEach((charObj) => {
      charObj.position += dt * speed;

      if (charObj.position > width) {
        charObj.position = -charObj.width;
      }

      const y = Math.sin(charObj.position / degrees) * amplitude;

      ctx.fillText(charObj.char, charObj.position, centerY + y);
    });
  };

  const animate = () => {
    const now = getTime();
    const dt = (now - previousTime) * 0.001 // delta time in seconds.
    previousTime = now;

    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    scrollText(dt);

    if (!paused) {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
  };

  start();

});




jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#can").appendTo("#saletop");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="salebanenr">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-12" id="saletop" style="border:1px solid black">
      test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```